# Can netezza database handle procedures?

Tags: netezza

I am having Netezza Database. I am querying the tables through DB visualiser. Since my table creation involves complex, I am interested to use procedures but I am unable to write it in DBvisualiser. I am confused whether the problem is with the tool that I use or in Netezza? Please advice

Answer (score 1):

Check out the free Aginity workbench tool. It's written specifically for Netezza & supports stored proc maintenance. URL is: http://www.aginity.com/workbench/

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can write procedures in Netezza. Netezza's flavor of SQL (NZSQL) was originally based on PostgreSQL (http://www.enzeecommunity.com/message/1400). It has user defined functions and procedures (http://www.enzeecommunity.com/servlet/JiveServlet/previewBody/1161-102-1-1107/Netezza_database_users_guide.pdf).

The Aginity Workbench for Netezza is a great way to author stored procedures (http://www.aginity.com/workbench/). Disclaimer - I work for Aginity.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use nzplsql language to write procedures.

If you are on Windows, install the Netezza Windows Client and you will find a "Stored Procedure Guide.pdf" in your start menu.

If you want to see some examples of procedures, I wrote an open source set of utilities for Netezza that is implemented with stored procedures.

You can see the nz-util documentation here: http://g14n.info/nz-util . There should be also a link to the GitHub repo where you can see sources.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to write stored procedure with multiple dml operation then refer to article at http://www.dataplatformexperts.com/writing-stored-procedure-in-netezza/

Comment: While the link may provide a good answer, you should provide a summary of the answer in your post (linked resources may be updated, removed, moved, etc).